# Deadlock still happens even relevant hint added

Tags: deadlock, hint

Deadlock happens on 2 indexed columns at table that updated by 2 procedures.
Deadlock happened on primary key (clustered index - PK_TableB_LID) and Non clustered index IX_TableB_PID_LogDate_LINDate (key locks)

Tried to add hint updlock but it didt help
This is the code of first and second procedures:

```
BEGIN
UPDATE top (10) pl
SET ModifiedDate = getdate(),
LogDate = getdate(),
LogRTypeID = 321
FROM dbo.TableA AS pac
INNER JOIN dbo.TableB AS pl WITH (READPAST) ON pl.PID = 5344
WHERE pac.AccessDate > '2023-02-01'
AND pl.LID =123899
END

UPDATE pl
SET ModifiedDate = getdate(),
LogDate = getdate(),
LogRTypeID= ISNULL(1, 323)
FROM dbo.TableB AS pl
WHERE PID = 123
```